# SoundCloud: Using the same account on multiple devices simultaneously?

Tags: ios, api, soundcloud

I am part of a three man team striving to create a audio oriented iOS app and we are currently using the SoundCloud API to power our streaming. We are in a very early stage of development but I thought it might be a good idea to ask you about some technicalities so that we don't have to realize we need to change our whole infastructure during the beta.

Since our app revolves around the user being able to create and listen to content we want to use one SoundCloud account to act as a component whose only task is to authenticate, upload and fetch the audio. The issue is that we need to access this account on every device running the app. If for example 100 people happen to use the app at the same time they would be using the same SoundCloud account at the same time. It would be logged into automatically and the only thing they would be able to do is record, upload, fetch and play audio from the account. Because of this I need to know:

1. Does authentication on one device deauthenticate the account from
   another? Is it possible to upload audio from one device from the
   same account as somebody else is listening at the same time? How
   about two people listening at the same time? Ten people listening at
   the same time?
2. Will the account get blocked if a user uploads something that is
   against your policy or will the audio just get removed? As far as I
   know the audio just gets removed, but I have not heard of accounts
   being blocked because of repeated policy disregard.

We are looking to use SoundCloud during beta and eventually get our own hosting up, but since the API and documentation is so friendly I thought we should see if SoundCloud would suit our needs.

Best regards,

Pär Strindevall

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to ask these questions the soundcloud support team. 
support AT soundcloud DOT com
@SCsupport

What i have learned so far:

Q1
You will stay logged on as long as the token is valid / not expired.
This should work - you can use your account on different devices at the same time.

Q2
I have the feeling that if they have detected a service which is not allowed by their terms of use for their api - they are blocking the host / origin the request is coming from and that particular field. But this is not confirmed by SC. I am waiting for an answer here.